# Digital sign of Email - VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have received a macro which was written by someone else and I need to repair it. It should digital sign e-mail. I have identified that this function causes an error:

```
Private Function AddControll(piIcon As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim oContr As Object
    Dim oCBs   As Object

    Set oContr = gmyMail.GetInspector.CommandBars.FindControl(, piIcon)
    If oContr Is Nothing Then
        Set oCBs = gmyMail.GetInspector.CommandBars
        Set oContr = oCBs.Item("Standard").Controls.Add(, piIcon, , , True)
    End If
End Function
```

gmyMail is type Outlook.MailItem and when should be e-mail signed digitally then this function is called with piIcon=719

I cannot find out what is wrong. Somewhere I have read that this codes for CommandBars changed since Outlook 2010 but I cannot find actual codes and also I am not sure what exactly this CommandBars should do... Does it assign an icon into the e-mail?

Comment: gmyMail is not Dim'd or  referenced in the function so is it a global variable? At the moment the code doesn't seem to be complete so you may find answers sparse. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yeah it is global variable (basically it is an email that is generated). There is a lot of code in the application but this relevant part of the code for the question I have asked...